# Advertising on the Stack network

Tags: discussion, advertising

I'm just curious how Stackoverflow + network sites handle advertising. How it's received, how it's displayed, etc.

I'm interested because I'm working on a network of sites my self (not related to any site in the Stackoverflow network), and I would like to learn how to handle advertising best.

Right now I've implemented an advertising system which will randomly pull ads stored in my database. The ads themselves are either affiliate network ads or custom publisher ads, but somehow I don't think I'm implementing it the way it should be, and I would like to extend my system to handle 3rd party publishers from networks that use JavaScript to embed ads for example.

My network is built on ASP.NET MVC 2.